# More accurate alternative to LongListSelector.ItemRealized

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

Im trying to add two way (up & down) infinite scrolling list to my WP8 app. So when list hits top, we load "smaller" items from web api and when list hit end, we load "bigger" items from web api.

My original idea was to use list like this, header and footer are set over screen.

```
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}" Margin="0,0,0,-90" ItemRealized="listBox_ItemRealized">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
                <Grid Margin="12,-90,12,30" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="Load more" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>

            <phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>
                <Grid Margin="12,30,12,0" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="Load more" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ListFooter>

            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="12,8" Background="#FFd3dae8" Width="456">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>



    void listBox_ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ItemKind == LongListSelectorItemKind.ListHeader)
        {
            // Get smaller items
        }

        else if (e.ItemKind == LongListSelectorItemKind.ListFooter)
        {
            // Get bigger items
        }
    }
```

Then I can use ListBox.ItemRealized to check when the header or footer gets realized and load more data based on that.

The problem is that I can get only 5 items from web api at once, so initially the list contains 5 items. That is ok, the list goes over the screen as my list item template is actually quite big and no footer or header are actually visible.

But the ItemRealized event is raised for each element, even when they are not actually visible. I think the problem is that LongListSelector actually loads 10(?) items at once and raises ItemRealized for all of them?

Is there any other techniques I can use to achieve this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the best approach. The LLS will "realize" (create/render) items before they are needed. This is a good thing. If it had to realize them at the moment they were going on the screen you would see a huge performance problem.

When your items are realized, you can add more items. Keep doing this until items are no longer realized.

I would suggest getting more than five items, that it a really low number of results to get from the server.

Comment: In this case usually 5 items in list is enough for user. But it would be great if user can just scroll up/down to get more results. It is totally out of my hands that I get only five items from server at once. Of course I can make multiple requests to get more items...

Comment: What Im really looking for is solution where I can exactly check when the list (Listbox or longlistselector) hits top or bottom. Then I can make web request and get more items.

Comment: You could hook into the ViewportControl as done in [this post](http://visuallylocated.com/post/2014/01/16/Synching-the-scroll-position-of-two-LongListSelectors.aspx)